# Capacitor Maximum Frequency of Operation

Tags: capacitor

[image]

**The correct answer is 760kHz.**

My Solution is:

- First find self-resonant capacitor frequency.
  Self-Resonant Frequency = 1/(2pi*sqrt(LC)) = 758kHz.
  From our second condition, we have that the capacitor must be operated less tahn 75.8kHz.
- Capacitor Impedance 1/(2*pi*f*C) > 10r, this leads to f < 72kHz.

Thus, I take the lower of these two conditions. **Hence, my answer is 72kHz. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong?

Comment: @ThePhoton The answer's incorrect according to the solutions we've been given. I double checked my calculations and I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so thought I might try here.

Comment: @ThePhoton 760kHz.

Comment: @ThePhoton If I did, wouldn't the correct solution still disobey the condition from the first bullet point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You followed all the instructions and got the correct answer that they requested.

But the question has false assumptions.

The cap is very good and is low Q ~1. Thus there is no significant resonance at the crossover frequency when the magnitude of impedance for L=C.  This means the impedance 1 decade above is about the same as 1 decade down is still useful .

[image]

Of course if you are using this cap. with a Buck Converter then the effects of the series inductor and interference with the loop filter spectrum  must be simulated to avoid stability issue .

[image]

Here SRF of 25kHz with a Q of 22 dB into a 10 Ohm load @  for a Buck SMPS perhaps operating much higher than  25kHz yet has good attenuation higher above this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however, I didn't get the correct answer. My answer was 72kHz, the correct solution given to us is 760kHz.

Comment: Based on the Q =1 the real correct answer is 10x 760kHz not 72kHz.  ... 760kHz is not  correct. In fact the attenuation at 10MHz is far more effective than 20kHz